# Solve an equation containing three unknown prime numbers

Tags: primes, equation-solving

I was recently asked a question in an interview & have been unable to crack it, after my own efforts have failed & Google not showing any results , I am posting it here so that anyone else may also try their hand on it .

Given the equation:

> ```
> a (a + b) = c - 120
> ```

where `a`,`b` & `c` are unequal prime numbers, find `a`, `b` & `c`.

I know I must use some property of the prime numbers to reduce the problem to a simpler one, but I can't think of one. Any suggestions/solutions will be appreciated.

The best I could come up with is that :

- There may be multiple solutions to it. My first approach was a brute force search for 3 prime numbers that solved this equations. (I know , totally useless)
- The second approach was a refinement of the first, to modify the equation to `a (a + b) - 120 = c`. So now we reduce our brute force variables to just a & b & check if the LHS is prime no for the selected `a` & `b`. (If `c` were to be large, finding out whether the LHS is a prime would take away the advantage gained by reducing the variables from 3 to 2.)

So you see, I am not really going anywhere.

Comment: The best I could come up with is that :

1) There may be multiple solutions to it . My first approach was a brute force search for 3 prime no's that solved this equations. (i know , totally useless)

2)The second approach was a refinement of the first, to modify the equation to a(a+b)-120=c. So now we reduce our brute force variables to just a & b & check if the LHS is prime no for the selected a & b.(If c were to be large , finding out whether the LHS is a prime would take away the advantage gained by reducing the variables from 3 to 2.)

So you see , i am not really going anywhere.

Comment: I note that you can rearrange that to `a^2+ba+(120-c)=0`, which is a quadratic on a which happens to have a couple of unknown coefficients (the coefficients are `(1, b, 120-c)`). Is that useful? Can you plug that into the standard quadratic formula and get anything of any use? Can you factorise it differently?

Comment: How many solutions are there if `a` and `b` are both odd?  How many solutions are there if `a` is 2?

Comment: @TomAnderson hmm... nice, but i now have 3 equations with a ,a^2,b,b^2,c . what next? I still think i must somehow use the fact that the numbers are prime to reduce the complexity of the problem.

Comment: What a bizarre question.  What was the position and where, if you don't mind my asking?  Wolfram?  :)

Answer (score 2):

all primes are odd, except 2 - (1)

all primes are positive - (2)

`odd - even = odd` (3)

(1), (2) => `c` > 120 and `c` is odd - (4)

`odd * odd = odd` - (5)

(3), (4), (5) => `c-120` is odd => `a(a+b)` is odd - (6)

`even + odd = odd` - (7)

(6) => `a` is odd, `a+b` is odd (8)

(7), (8) => `b` is even => **`b` = 2**

So, we have `a^2 + 2a = c-120`

I couldn't go any further

Comment: The answer is: `a=11, b=2, c=263` - found by bruteforce

Answer (score 2):

Let's stipulate that c > 120.  That implies c != 2.  So the RHS is odd.

Therefore the LHS has to be odd, so a (a + b) has to be odd.  So a is odd, and a+b is odd.  This only works out if b is even, and b is prime, so b = 2.

So we have a(a+2) = c - 120.

So a^2 + 2a + (120-c) = 0

Using the quadratic formula, solving for a, we get

[-2 +- sqrt(2^2 - 4 * 1 * (120 - c))] / 2

= -1 +- sqrt(1 - (120-c))

= -1 + sqrt(c - 119)

So we need a prime number c, so that c - 119 is a perfect square.

This is a quick calculation with a table of primes.

The smallest one I can find is c = 263, so a = 11, b = 2

It looks like c=443, a=17, b=2 also works.

There don't appear to be any other c values below 1000.

Possibly there are many, many others.

Comment: No need to search for squares, just check that `c=a(a+2)+120` is prime: `[(a,c) | a<-primes, let c=a*(a+2)+120, isPrime c]` produces `[(11,263),(17,443),(29,1019),(47,2423),(59,3719),(71,5303),(89,8219),(107,11783),(137,19163), ... (2999,9000119),(3119,9734519), ... (122777,15074437403),(122819,15084752519), ...`.

Comment: `... (316067,99898980743),(316241,100009002683), ... (547499,299756250119),(547871,300163728503), ... (1000037,1000076001563),(1000199,1000400040119), ...` . BTW just searching for squares as you describe is insufficient, because there's no guarantee for `a` to be prime, calculated that way back from `c`, only to be odd. Indeed there are such non-prime `a`s: `(77,6203),(119,14519),(287,83063)...`.